# Find the angle of a line with the x-axis, given the two co-ordinates

Tags: geometry

I have the co-ordinates of a line. They are in the form x, y. I need to find the angle this line makes with the x axis. Both the points can be edited by the user in my application, hence I cannot hold one as the center of rotation. I have tried this:

```
theta = tan-inv((y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1))
```

I consider the right point as x2, y2 and the left point as x1, y1 always. But I'm not getting the right value. Also, I need to convert the value returned in such a way that I can apply it on the canvas (between 0 - 360).

Note: I convert the values to degrees/radians whenever and wherever it is required.

I have attached an image that should explain what I'm trying in more detail.

[image]

Comment: That's what I'm using! But returns wrong values!

Answer (score -1):

This expression

```
(y2 - y1/x2 - x1)
```

is bracketed incorrectly, it should be

```
((y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1))
```

If you now explain that what you have posted is not really your code I will downvote this question for wasting my time.  I could also do with some reassurance that you understand the difference between *radians* and *degrees* and the different conventions that mathematicians and navigators use for indicating angles around a circle.

Comment: Obviously it's bracketed and I do the proper radian/degree conversion in my code! What I've posted is just a pseudo code, to show what I'm trying. I can't post the real code, it's not even required since I've explained a general problem. I got a line expressed by the 2 points and I need to find the angle it makes with the x axis.